# Properly binding values to prevent duplication

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have 5 fields for a user to fill in: Leave Code, From Date, Input Time1, To Date, Input Time2. I have these variables declared as a dates object in my .ts file as shown in this snippet.

```
interface Supervisor {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}
interface LeaveCode {
  name: string;
  code: string;
}

 ngOnInit() {
   this.dates = [ ];

  }
  supervisor2: Supervisor[];
  selectedSupervisor2: Supervisor;
  leaveCodes2: LeaveCode[];
  selectedLeaveCode2: LeaveCode;
  dates: {leaveCode:string, fromDate: string, fromTime: string, toDate:string, toTime:string}[];

  minDate: Date;
  maxDate: Date;
  fromDate: Date;
  toDate: Date;
  fromDateMin: Date;
  toDateMin: Date;
  fromDateMax: Date;
  toDateMax: Date;
  fromTime: Date;
  toTime: Date;

 if (this.dates.length < 8)
      this.dates.push({leaveCode:"",  fromDate: "", fromTime: "", toDate:"", toTime:""});
  }
```

in my .html file I have declared these fields as followed. My issue is that when I press the addbutton to generate a new row of inputs, the values on the inputs stay the same as the rest of the values in that column. How should I properly bind these values!

```
<p-dropdown [options]="leaveCodes2" [(ngModel)]="selectedleaveCodes2" name="selectedleaveCodes2" placeholder="Leave Code*" optionLabel="name" required></p-dropdown>

<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" name="fromDate" [minDate]="minDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="From Date*" id="setter" required></p-calendar>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fromTime" name="fromTime" placeholder="Input Time*" style="height: 2.186em" size="7" maxlength="8" pInputText required>

<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="toDate" name="toDate" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [readonlyInput]="true" placeholder="To Date*" id="setter" required></p-calendar>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="toTime" name="toTime" placeholder="Input Time*" style="height: 2.186em" size="7" maxlength="8" pInputText required>

<button pButton type="button" id="addButton" icon="pi pi-plus" class="ui-button-success" (click)="onAddClicked()"></button>
```

Any help would be appreciated, or any suggested readings would be useful too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> **Please use reactive form approch for more complex form**

First create FormGroup for suppose fields Which you wanna make form.
here i guess fields are

```
public dateForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  selectedleaveCodes2: new FormControl(''), 
  fromDate: new FormControl(''),
  fromTime: new FormControl(''),
  toDate: new FormControl(''),
  toTime: new FormControl(''),
});
```

Now Add this to your main formGroup suppose main formGroup is

```
public mainForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  dateFields: new FormArray([]);
});
```

Now Suppose you wanna add another item in formArray 
let's create a helper method that will do this work of adding **dateForm** from **mainForm**

```
  private getDateForm(): FormGroup {
      return new FormGroup({
          selectedleaveCodes2: new FormControl(''), 
          fromDate: new FormControl(''),
          fromTime: new FormControl(''),
          toDate: new FormControl(''),
          toTime: new FormControl(''),
        });
   }
```

Now to add new item in FormArray

```
this.mainForm.get('dateFields').push(this.getDateForm());
```

For remove at index

```
this.mainForm.get('dateFields').removeAt(index);
```

now in html you have to do this

```
<div *ngFor="let group in mainForm.get('dateFields')['controls'];let i = index">
  <div [formGroup]='group'>
    <p-calendar formControlName="selectedleaveCodes2"></p-calendar>
    <p-calendar formControlName="fromDate"></p-calendar>
    <p-calendar formControlName="fromTime"></p-calendar>
    <p-calendar formControlName="toDate"></p-calendar>
    <p-calendar formControlName="toTime"></p-calendar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in submit call ->

```
const value = this.mainForm.value;
```

**which will look something like**

```
{
     dateFields: [{
        selectedleaveCodes2: "your data",
        fromDate: "your data",
        fromTime: "your data",
        toDate: "your data",
        toTime: "your data",
    }, 
    {
        selectedleaveCodes2: "your second data",
        fromDate: "your second data",
        fromTime: "your second data",
        toDate: "your second data",
        toTime: "your second data",
    }]
}
```

For more info

https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/